# Android: On Switching from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a doubt. When switching from one activity to another. Sometimes, there appears a black screen. Is it possible to make it as a loading screen or something like that?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: Where is your code? You must be doing some time consuming task while switching from one activity to another.

Answer (score 1):

You can override default behavior between transition of Activities by :

```
startActivity(i);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.sliding_left,R.anim.sliding_right);
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a loading screen instead??